# Reload the tabs in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tabs, ionic-framework

I have a problem!

I have 2 tabs with user's info and in the header-bar 1 switch to change the user. I use this:

```
$state.transitionTo($state.current, $stateParams, {
    reload: true,
    inherit: false,
    notify: true
  });
```

With this i change the user in the title but the tabs don't show this change, I need refresh de app with f5.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)** to reload your app like this:

```
$location.path('/url')
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but not found. Could load start the tab's content with ng-load or similar?